# My Spring MVC error "HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed;

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, session

I have trouble with my SPRING_MVC project Can anyone help me!    I debug and it happen at SessionFactory return null

```
// my UserDaoImpl.java
    @Override
    public User getUser(String username, String pass) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println(session);
        User user = (User) session.get(User.class, username);
        if (user == null)
            return null;
        if (user.getUsername().equals(pass))
            return user;
        return user;
    }
```

1. List item

> It's error
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at luongnm.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.getUser(UserDaoImpl.java:71)
>         at luongnm.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.main(UserDaoImpl.java:66)
>        4. my file: data-source-hiber.cfg.xml like:

Can anybody help me, thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: Please check again your dataSource and sessionFactory configuration to make sure that they are both correct.

Comment: My datasource: <bean id="myDataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mp3" />
  <!-- sua lai password moi chay dc -->
  <property name="username" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="12345" />
 </bean>

Comment: Session : : :  : :<bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
 </bean>